# Javascript finding parent or sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html code:

```
<div class="comment" id="7" >
  <div style="display:inline-block">
    <img style="width:64px;height:64px" src="http://origin.black-marketplace.net/content/images/users/1.jpg"><br>
    <div class="rating" style="background-position:0px -10px" title="1 stelle su 5"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;float:right;width:172px;height:75px">
    <b>Xriuk</b>
    <div style="font-size:10px;color:#BEBEBE;line-height:10px">ha comprato</div>
    <span class="ellips games">mkx brteshtnx</span>
  </div>
  <span style="font-size:12px;height:50px;width:236px;display:block" class="ellips">sdjchsdui edi0ufwuèè+eè+è+èàùiek ci0hxjomwui9vjko'asdhvfyu8rk cxi0ehfuioweju9cwej icjnweuceioncuiasn cu9wecji0wejucm vuiom fiwefdoeqr hg wgtehwhwtwghrh</span>
  <a class="url" style="float:right;font-size:11px;display:none" href="7">Continua a leggere -&gt;</a>
</div>
```

Basically all the elements with the class **ellips** get ellipsed if overflow the size of the box, what I want to do is to **display** the  if any of two span contains the string "**...**".

What I already did:

```
$(".ellips").ellipsis();
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("ellips");
if(text){
  for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    if(text[i].innerHTML.indexOf("...") != "-1"){
      ***HERE***
    }
  }
}
```

In `***HERE***` I need to put a code which returns the child element "**#url**" of the top parent element "**.comment**" (the top parent element must correspond to the current "**.ellips**" selected).
Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(".ellips").ellipsis();
$('.comment .ellips').each(function () {
    if (this.innerHTML.indexOf("...") != "-1") {
        var $url = $(this).closest('.comment').find('.url');
        //here $url refers the element with url class under the same .comment element
    }
})
```

Comment: And if I only want to parse "**.ellips**" in "**.comment**"?

Comment: @Xriuk what do you mean by parse `ellips`

Comment: I have multiple "**.ellips**" elements even outside "**.comment**" class. I need to use that function only with the "**.ellips**" in "**.comment**"

Comment: @Xriuk `$('.comment .ellips').each(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $(text[i]).closest('.comment').find('a.url')
```